# Hide svg at start and still being animatable with animjs (opacity: 1) again

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Let's take this simple svg as an example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 

xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 31.49 31.49" style="enable-background:new 0 0 31.49 31.49;" xml:space="preserve">
<path style="fill:#1E201D;"
      d="M21.205,5.007c-0.429-0.444-1.143-0.444-1.587,0c-0.429,0.429-0.429,1.143,0,1.571l8.047,8.047H1.111  C0.492,14.626,0,15.118,0,15.737c0,0.619,0.492,1.127,1.111,1.127h26.554l-8.047,8.032c-0.429,0.444-0.429,1.159,0,1.587  c0.444,0.444,1.159,0.444,1.587,0l9.952-9.952c0.444-0.429,0.444-1.143,0-1.571L21.205,5.007z"/>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
```

In the beginning of my script when the doc has loaded, I find the element and hides it.

```
const loading_svg = document.getElementById('loading-svg');

 // initialize server-svg as invisible
anime({
    targets: [loading_svg],
    opacity: 0
});
```

However, that resolves in some issues:  [See example](https://gyazo.com/7a5bf40da572f403029231122148c7dd)

**The goal**

The goal is now to later have it appear when the user hover over something; therefor it is important to have it initialized as hidden to start off. Now, this is a bad approach, as it is first able to hide the svg when the document has loaded, which means that it is going to look something like this: (note that you can see the svg in a split second before it dissappearing) [See example](https://gyazo.com/7a5bf40da572f403029231122148c7dd)

**What have I tried?**

I have tried setting the opacity css attribute of the svg to 0. Then when the user has hovered over a specific item tried doing:

```
// initialize server-svg as invisible
anime({
    targets: [loading_svg],
    opacity: 1
});
```

However, that does not work.

I am not sure how `animejs` hides svg's whenever you set the opacity attribute to 0, but it doesn't seem like it sets the css opacity attribute of the svg to 0. This also explains why it animejs is unable to "unhide" the svg if its css opacity attribute is sat to 0.

**Simplified fiddle demonstrating the issue:**

```js
anime({
        targets: document.getElementsByTagName('svg'),
        opacity: 1
    });
```

```css
svg {
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 31.49 31.49" style="enable-background:new 0 0 31.49 31.49;" xml:space="preserve">
<path style="fill:#1E201D;"

      d="M21.205,5.007c-0.429-0.444-1.143-0.444-1.587,0c-0.429,0.429-0.429,1.143,0,1.571l8.047,8.047H1.111  C0.492,14.626,0,15.118,0,15.737c0,0.619,0.492,1.127,1.111,1.127h26.554l-8.047,8.032c-0.429,0.444-0.429,1.159,0,1.587  c0.444,0.444,1.159,0.444,1.587,0l9.952-9.952c0.444-0.429,0.444-1.143,0-1.571L21.205,5.007z"/>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.js"></script>
```

Comment: The fiddle has a type error. Please look at this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nz0md8b1/1/)

Comment: I fixed that. Uh, you did too I see.

Comment: But the original fiddle doesn't have the fix. You should update the fiddle cuz everyone will see the one with the error.

Comment: Wait... This is strange. It actually works in the fiddle, perhaps it doesn't work in my own script because I load the svg as:          <object id="loading-svg" style="position: absolute; bottom: 100px; left: 393px;" height="37px;" type="image/svg+xml" data="svg/loading.svg"></object>

Comment: This code would be much more readable without the blank group elements inside the svg.  BTW, you don't need this animjs script to show/hide an icon. Just use regular css.

Comment: Here is the fiddle for pure css solution: https://jsfiddle.net/nz0md8b1/4/

Comment: I have a large animation going on, and this need to be shown after x sec in the sequence as well as do some other stuff. So I think that it would be best to continue using animejs.

Comment: Sure. I guess you now know that the script works and you made an error somewhere along the way. Good luck debugging!